# Set up Delegate relationship between two views and send messages

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicontainerview

In iOS, I am building an app in Swift. I have a View with a container view set up within it, linking an embedded view. This has been set up using Storyboards.

How do I set up a delegate relationship between the views in Swift code so that I can send messages / trigger functions in one view from the other?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have two views `ViewA` and `ViewB`

Instance of `ViewB` is created inside `ViewA`, so `ViewA` can send message to `ViewB's` instance, but for the reverse to happen we need to implement delegation (so that using delegate `ViewB's` instance could send message to ViewA)

*Follow these steps to implement the delegation*

1) In `ViewB` create protocol as

```
protocol ViewBDelegate{
    func delegateMethod(controller:ViewB, text:String)
}
```

2) Declare the delegate in the sender class

```
class ViewB: UIView {
    var delegate: ViewBDelegate! = nil
}
```

3) Use the method in class to call the delegate method as

```
@IBAction func callDelegateMethod(sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
        delegate!. delegateMethod(self, text: colorLabel.text)
 //assuming the delegate is assigned otherwise error
}
```

4) Adopt the protocol in ClassA

```
class ViewA: UIView, ViewBDelegate {
```

5) Implement the delegate

```
func delegateMethod(controller: ViewB, text: String) {
    label.text = "The text is " +  text
}
```

6) Set the delegate

```
override func anyFuction() 
{
      // create ViewB instance and set the delegate
      viewB.delegate = self
}
```

**Note** : This is just the rough idea of delegation in swift between two classes, you can customize it as per your requirements.

Comment: Hi Sanjay! Just confused by step 6! Where would I type this code? Could you also expand how to "create ViewB instance and set the delegate"?

Comment: Hello Max, step 6 is just for illustration(it's a sample function). there could be some event where you are creating the instance of viewB, just after you created the instance of viewB set the delegate there.

Comment: you can create ViewB instance inside any method of class ViewA and set the delegate as-
var viewBInstance: ViewB = ViewB()
viewBInstance.delegate = self

Comment: now class ViewA can send messages to class ViewB using it's instance 'viewBInstance' and as we have set the delegate property of the viewBInstance to self(which is viewA's reference), so incase if class ViewB wants to send a message to instance of class ViewA, it can use it's delegate variable(and as delegate variable is holding reference of class viewA, so calling a method on delegate will send the corresponding message to class ViewA's instance).

Comment: in this way two classes can communicate with each other. ViewA to ViewB by simple messaging and ViewB to ViewA via delegation.

Comment: Marked this as correct, because it is, but for others trying to solve this, I found this article helpful to me in working out where to put each piece of code: http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/

Comment: @Max ya definately, it's a helpful article.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique identifier for your embed segue.

In the parent view controller, implement the prepareForSegue method.

Use a switch statement to match the segue identifier. In the case for your contained view controller, fetch the destination view controller property from the segue, cast it to the type for your custom destination view controller, and set it's delegate property.

If you need a way to send parent-to-child messages on a continuing basis, you should also save a pointer to your child view controller in prepareForSegue.

(You will also need to define a protocol to communicate from the child to the parent, and set up the parent to conform to that protocol. You should use a name other than "delegate" for the delegate property. Say you call it `ParentVCDelegate" (Since lots of Apple's classes like UITableViewController already have a delegate property.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to use a segue here?  In a previous project I made an overloaded UIView controller that would pass data from controller to controller.

We had a data container class called `RestFlightVariables` and another container called `rest` which both stored specific information to be passed between controllers.

Then we created `RESTUIViewController` which had an overloaded `prepareForSegue` function.  If the class the controller was segueing to was also a `RESTUIViewController` the variables `rest` and `restVars` would be passed on.

```
/**
RESTUIViewController is an overloaded UIVIewcontroller that handles the     passing of REST variables between view controllers
*/
class RESTUIViewController : ResponsiveTextFieldViewController {
    var rest : RESTInterface?
    var restVars : RESTFlightVariables?

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("----- RESTUIViewController Segue -----")
    let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as RESTUIViewController
        nextVC.rest = self.rest
        nextVC.restVars = self.restVars
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Another alternative could be to use the **NSNotification** System, but this isn't really appropriate when you are passing data between views.  **Segues** is a more appropriate method of data passing.